# Display data on gridview from ftp See more: C#ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have too many files on ftp server which I want to display in data gridview without saving or downloading and sort by date. These files are .qrt but I can open them in excel or notepad.

I did that but from sql db but never worked with ftp.
These files have names with dates.

I'm using asp.net web forms in C#.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to show the file content from Ftp in gridview ? Did you try reading file as text file and convert the data into c# class collection?

Comment: is this one FTP folder, or is this a typical hierarchy of folders? But, yes, a grid view is a great way to show a list of ftp files - and is quite easy. However, if this is to be folder like view of the ftp files, then a treeview control is of course much better - as then you can display a file explorer like UI. But, which choice depends on how you want to display the files - so is this to be one FTP folder with files (grid view good), or do you need/want to display a folder like UI? but, the answer is yes here - we just need to know if this is one folder or many folders you wish to display.

Comment: its 1 FTP folder, can you please give me a sample of code for the treeview as i never used it before. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as noted is quite easy. But, you don't mention if you have a bunch of folders that you want to display, or just files from one FTP folder?

As noted, if you have a bunch of folders, then VERY easy to use a tree view to display this hierarchy type setup. However, for one folder? Sure, a GridView is a great choice.

You can say use this:

our markup is thus this:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
  CssClass="table" Width="20%"></asp:GridView>
```

Ok, and our code is this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

So, for page load, we have this:

```
   const string UserId = "User Name here";
    const string Password = "Password here";
    const string fRoot = "ftp://ftp.mycoolwebsite.com/test";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }


    void LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable MyFiles = new DataTable();
        MyFiles.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));

        List<string> fList = GetFtpFiles();
        foreach (string sFile in fList)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = MyFiles.NewRow();
            OneRow["File"] = sFile;
            MyFiles.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = MyFiles;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    List<string> GetFtpFiles()
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpR = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fRoot);
        ftpR.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserId, Password);
        ftpR.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        FtpWebResponse response = ftpR.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;

        StreamReader sread = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        List<string> myDir = new List<string>();

        string oneLine = sread.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oneLine))
        {
            myDir.Add(oneLine);
            oneLine = sread.ReadLine();
        }
        sread.Close();
        return myDir;
    }
```

And out output is now this:

[image]

Now, if we want the file size? that's a problem, since in theory ONCE we have the file list, we could cook up code to "request" each file size - that's a pain, but WORSE is a lot of requests. The other way, is we can change this:

```
        ftpR.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```

to:

```
        ftpR.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
```

The above will return file information VERY much like an old style DOS file listing.

When we run above with above, we now get this:

[image]

So, if we want to sort say by file name, we have to parse out the file name, and date. This is not too hard. As noted, the other way is to "request" the file size an date for each file - but that is extra code, but WORSE is a LOT of hits to the ftp server.

And the style of the file listings are not consistent from web servers (might be windows, or linux), but we COULD parse out the above into columns - and then we can sort by date, or file name.

Parsing? Gee, this works:

```
  void LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable MyFiles = new DataTable();
        MyFiles.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        MyFiles.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(int));
        MyFiles.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));

        List<string> fList = GetFtpFiles();

        foreach (string s in fList)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = MyFiles.NewRow();
            string sRow = s;
            while (sRow.Contains("  "))
                sRow = sRow.Replace("  ", " ");
            
            sRow = sRow.Replace(" ", ",");
            string[] scols = sRow.Split(',');
            OneRow["Size"] = scols[4];
            OneRow["File"] = scols[8];
            OneRow["Date"] = scols[7] + "-" + scols[6] + "-" + scols[5];

            MyFiles.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = MyFiles;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

We need to formt that ate in the grid - but at least now, with a table, you can sort that table by date, or filename before you bind it, say like this:

```
        MyFiles.DefaultView.Sort = "File";
        GridView1.DataSource = MyFiles;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

And you can/could sort by date also - since we defined date column as datetime.

Comment: Thank you SO much for taking the time and effort to help me. its works fine but when i add the last code it gives me : Index was outside the bounds of the array. at this line: OneRow["Size"] = scols[4]; but if i dont add this block of code it works as you mentioned.

Comment: as noted, try filling out the grid as just one collum. You have to write code to parse out that "directory" listing - and as noted, this will vary from server to server. So, I removed all blanks (double spaces) until they are all gone. I then split based on a "," between each column. I then pluck out the column - you have to tweak and play with that part of the code, since as noted, what "directly" listing your server spits out will vary and be somewhat different then my example.  So, you might even debug-print, get one line of the directory list - put it in a text file - and parse it out.

Comment: In other words, writing that pluck-out and parse out of that one line folder listing is tricky - and you have to hand code this and figure out how much different your folder listing works and looks from my example. In place of a split, you could also take the starting + end character position, and parse out that way - they re fixed listing size - but as noted, what you see will no doubt be somewhat different then my directly listing. this is a text parsing problem. I can also post a treeview version if you want - that might be better since treeview allows check box select of the files.

Comment: I really cant thank you enough! You are awesome!